# SQL Nested COUNT for gurus

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, nested

Current code:

```
SELECT "conversation"."id", "conversation"."title", "conversation"."deleted", "conversation"."created_at", (
        SELECT  COUNT("currentUserConversations->messageReceivers"."id")
        FROM "Conversations" AS "conversation"
        INNER JOIN "UserConversation" AS "currentUserConversations" ON "conversation"."id" = "currentUserConversations"."conversation_id"
        INNER JOIN "MessageReceiver" AS "currentUserConversations->messageReceivers" ON "currentUserConversations"."id" = "currentUserConversations->messageReceivers"."user_conversation_id" AND "currentUserConversations->messageReceivers"."read" = false
        WHERE "currentUserConversations"."user_id" = 7
        ) AS "unreadM" 
FROM "Conversations" AS "conversation" 
INNER JOIN "UserConversation" AS "otherUserConversations" ON "conversation"."id" = "otherUserConversations"."conversation_id" 
INNER JOIN "UserConversation" AS "currentUserConversations" ON "conversation"."id" = "currentUserConversations"."conversation_id" 
INNER JOIN "MessageReceiver" AS "currentUserConversations->messageReceivers" ON "currentUserConversations"."id" = "currentUserConversations->messageReceivers"."user_conversation_id"
WHERE "currentUserConversations"."user_id" = 7 
AND "otherUserConversations"."user_id" = '4' 
GROUP BY "conversation"."id";
```

My Tables:

- Conversations
- UserConversation
- MessageReceiver

Relationships:

- N `UserConversation` per `Conversations`
- 1 `MessageReceiver` per `UserConversation`

What I'm trying to accomplish:

- `MessageReceiver` has a `read` column
- `MessageReceiver`.`read` can be true/false
- for the given query (everything outside the nested query) I want to count how many MessageReceivers has the `read` column set as `false` (and return it in the main query aliased as `unreadM`)

What's currently happening:

The nested query count all the MessageReceivers, even if they have the `read` propriety set to `true`...

Using PostgreSQL dialect.

If possible I would appreciate an approach that doesn't changes the "FROM". I also need to be able to filter the outer query to (conditionally, not in sql, but from express, generating the query based on external conditions) only retrieve conversations where there is atleast 1 unread message (`"currentUserConversations->messageReceivers"."read" = false`)

My brain is exploding, if anyone has a solution and an explanation I would really much appreciate it!

Expected Results:

```
id   title                         deleted   created_at              unreadM
4   "automaticSeeded title shvrn"   false   "2018-11-26 13:24:33.766355+01" "0"
7   "automaticSeeded title viowy"   false   "2018-11-26 13:24:33.766355+01" "4"
```

Returned Results:

```
id   title                         deleted   created_at              unreadM
4   "automaticSeeded title shvrn"   false   "2018-11-26 13:24:33.766355+01" "4"
7   "automaticSeeded title viowy"   false   "2018-11-26 13:24:33.766355+01" "4"
```

Sample Data:

UserConversation

```
id|conversation_id|user_id|deleted|admin
1|10|1|f|f
2|10|10|f|f
3|9|2|f|f
4|9|9|f|f
5|8|3|f|f
6|8|8|f|f
8|7|7|f|f
10|6|6|f|f
11|5|6|f|f
12|5|5|f|f
13|4|7|f|f
14|4|4|f|f
15|3|8|f|f
16|3|3|f|f
17|2|9|f|f
18|2|2|f|f
19|1|10|f|f
20|1|1|f|f
7|7|4|f|f
9|6|7|f|f
```

MessageReceiver:

```
id|user_conversation_id|message_id|read
1|1|1|t
2|1|2|t
3|1|3|t
4|1|4|t
5|2|5|t
6|2|6|t
7|2|7|t
8|2|8|t
9|3|9|t
10|3|10|t
11|3|11|t
12|3|12|t
17|5|17|t
18|5|18|t
19|5|19|t
20|5|20|t
21|6|21|t
22|6|22|t
23|6|23|t
24|6|24|t
29|8|29|f
30|8|30|f
31|8|31|f
32|8|32|f
33|9|33|t
34|9|34|t
35|9|35|t
36|9|36|t
37|10|37|t
38|10|38|t
39|10|39|t
40|10|40|t
41|11|41|t
42|11|42|t
43|11|43|t
44|11|44|t
45|12|45|f
46|12|46|f
47|12|47|f
48|12|48|f
49|13|49|t
50|13|50|t
51|13|51|t
52|13|52|t
53|14|53|t
54|14|54|t
55|14|55|t
56|14|56|t
57|15|57|t
58|15|58|t
59|15|59|t
60|15|60|t
61|16|61|f
62|16|62|f
63|16|63|f
64|16|64|f
65|17|65|t
66|17|66|t
67|17|67|t
68|17|68|t
69|18|69|t
70|18|70|t
71|18|71|t
72|18|72|t
73|19|73|t
74|19|74|t
75|19|75|t
76|19|76|t
77|20|77|f
78|20|78|f
79|20|79|f
80|20|80|f
25|7|25|t
26|7|26|t
14|4|14|t
13|4|13|t
16|4|16|t
15|4|15|t
27|7|27|t
28|7|28|t
```

Conversations:

```
id|title|deleted|created_at
1|automaticSeeded title ijmmg|f|2018-11-26 13:24:33.766355+01
2|automaticSeeded title xdjiy|f|2018-11-26 13:24:33.766355+01
3|automaticSeeded title bmvpv|f|2018-11-26 13:24:33.766355+01
4|automaticSeeded title shvrn|f|2018-11-26 13:24:33.766355+01
5|automaticSeeded title yjvai|f|2018-11-26 13:24:33.766355+01
6|automaticSeeded title ubzab|f|2018-11-26 13:24:33.766355+01
7|automaticSeeded title viowy|f|2018-11-26 13:24:33.766355+01
8|automaticSeeded title ecthq|f|2018-11-26 13:24:33.766355+01
9|automaticSeeded title tzotl|f|2018-11-26 13:24:33.766355+01
10|automaticSeeded title fakjf|f|2018-11-26 13:24:33.766355+01
```

Comment: Expected result for sample data would help.

Comment: Added Expected results VS returned results @RadimBača

Comment: sample data are missing

Comment: What kind of sample data you want? tell me and I will deliver (the database is filled with unrelevant data, it's all in development state)

Comment: Some data in tables and expected result for this data

Comment: Added the relevant tables sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not completely clear what you are trying to achieve, but your subquery is independent. It means that you will obtain always the same result for all rows in `unreadM`.

However, I believe that you want the following

```
SELECT c."id", c."title", c."deleted", c."created_at", 
    Count(
        CASE WHEN mr."read" = false THEN 1 END
    ) AS "unreadM" 
FROM "Conversations" AS c 
INNER JOIN "UserConversation" AS ouc ON c."id" = ouc."conversation_id" 
INNER JOIN "UserConversation" AS uc ON c."id" = uc."conversation_id" 
INNER JOIN "MessageReceiver" AS mr ON uc."id" = mr."user_conversation_id"
WHERE uc."user_id" = 7 
AND ouc."user_id" = 4 
GROUP BY c."id";
```

If you would do `count(*) + where read = false` instead of `count(case when read = false ...)` then you would lost conversations without unread messages.

Moreover, I would include all the conversation columns that you want in the output into the `GROUP BY` list. Just to meet the others DBMS requirements.

```
...
GROUP BY c."id", c."title", c."deleted", c."created_at";
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, never used `CASE`, could you explain me why it is required and i can't do it with a normal COUNT(column)from ... where read=false ?

Comment: FYI, the query as written will not work on postgresql, because postgresql requires all not aggregated fields to be present in the group by clause. i.e. the group by _has to be_ `GROUP BY c.id, c.title, c.deleted, c.created_at`

Comment: i'm not sure why but it's actually working in my version of postgreSQL, but i'm using a ORM in my project, which mean it could get automatically filled with the relevant group by clausle, I will add the explicit declaration of the group by columns as you specified, thanks a lot!